# How to pass list object to html string?

Tags: html, reactjs

The puzzle here that I am trying to solve is, how to show a list of items in another components as a string.`html={listLocationsAsTextt}` The end goal is to show that list each object in separate row as well.
I am trying to use ReachTextFoldout component that needs html as string as it uses sanitized `const sanitizedHTML = DOMPurify.sanitize(html, sanitizeConfig)` .
Could anyone see a way around this?

```
import React, { FC } from "react"
import * as S from "./styles/FeatureInfoStyles"
import * as T from "./types/FeaturedInfoTypes"

import RichTextFoldout from "components/molecules/richTextFoldout/RichTextFoldout"

const FeaturedInfo: FC<T.Props> = (p) => {
  const hasMoreThanThreeLocations = p.locations.length > 3

  const splitLocations = React.useCallback(() => {
    const maxLength = 3

    const firstThreeLocations = p.locations.slice(0, maxLength)
    const restLocations = p.locations.slice(maxLength, p.locations.length)

    return [firstThreeLocations, restLocations]
  }, [p.locations])

  const [firstThreeLocations, restLocations] = splitLocations()
  // Iterate over the locations and create a list of them
  const idontbelievethis = (
    <ul>
      {restLocations.map((location: any) => (
        <li key={location}>
          {location.city}, {location.state}, {location.country}.
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )

  const listLocationsAsTextt = `${`<p><strong>${idontbelievethis}</p>`}`

  return (
    <S.View>
      {p.category && <S.Detail>{p.category}</S.Detail>}
      {p.experienceLevel && <S.Detail>{p.experienceLevel}</S.Detail>}
      {p.employmentType && <S.Detail>{p.employmentType}</S.Detail>}
      {hasMoreThanThreeLocations ? (
        <S.Header>
          {firstThreeLocations.map(
            (location: any, index: React.Key | undefined) => (
              <li key={index}>
                {location.city}, {location.state}, {location.country}.
              </li>
            )
          )}

          <RichTextFoldout
            html={listLocationsAsTextt}
            bgColor={""}
            height={0}
            maxHeight={10}
          />
        </S.Header>
      ) : (
        <S.Header>
          {firstThreeLocations.map(
            (location: any, index: React.Key | undefined) => (
              <li key={index}>
                {location.city}, {location.state}, {location.country}.
              </li>
            )
          )}
        </S.Header>
      )}
    </S.View>
  )
}

export default FeaturedInfo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';

// ...
const listLocationsAsText = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
  <p>
    <strong>
      <ul>
        {restLocations.map((location: any) => (
          <li>
            {location.city}, {location.state}, {location.country}.
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </strong>
  </p>
);
```

Comment: Had to clean it out a bit as well. 

`const listLocationsAsText = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
    restLocations.map((location: any, index: React.Key | undefined) => (
      <li key={index}>
        {location.city}, {location.state}, {location.country}.
      </li>
    ))
  )
`